# read line by line and take a string in line and assign that string to the subsequent line using perl

Tags: text-processing, perl

Data file is fixed length file, and I want to read file line by line and take a string from the current line, and then append that string to the subsequent line and write into another file.

For example1, given the file:

```
AAABBBB11115678xxxx
BBBCCCC22221234YYYY
MTD0001abcdARN12345 abcdedfg
AA 0002bcde
BB 0003defg
CCCDDDD33331234zzzz
MTD0003qwerTRN56789 defghigk
AA 9876bvcn
BB 8765zxcv
XXXBBBB11115678aaaa
YYYCCCC22221234bbbb
```

The output should be:

```
AAABBBB11115678xxxx
BBBCCCC22221234YYYY
MTD0001abcdARN12345 abcdedfg
AA 0002bcdeARN12345
BB 0003defgARN12345
CCCDDDD33331234zzzz
MTD0003qwerARN56789 defghigk
AA 9876bvcnARN56789
BB 8765zxcvARN56789
XXXBBBB11115678aaaa
YYYCCCC22221234bbbb
```

For example2, given the file:

```
AAABBBB11115678xxxxbedfgd
BBBCCCC22221234YYYYabcd
MTD0001abcdARN12345 abcdedfg 12345abcd
AA 0002bcde
BB 0003defg
CCCDDDD33331234zzzzqwerty
MTD0003qwerTRN56789 defghigk 45677defg
AA 9876bvcn
BB 8765zxcv
XXXBBBB11115678aaaazeftfy
YYYCCCC22221234bbbbefgydy
```

The output should be:

```
AAABBBB11115678xxxxbedfgd
BBBCCCC22221234YYYYabcd
MTD0001abcdARN12345 abcdedfg 12345abcd
AA 0002bcdeARN12345
BB 0003defgARN12345
CCCDDDD33331234zzzzqwerty
MTD0003qwerARN56789 defghigk 45677defg
AA 9876bvcnARN56789
BB 8765zxcvARN56789
XXXBBBB11115678aaaazeftfy
YYYCCCC22221234bbbbefgydy
```

I need to implement the above example 2 this with Perl?

Comment: Why is TRN changed to ARN at line 7? Why is the `abcdedfg` part not copied to the next line, too?

Comment: Oh, its actually ARN only and I want only ARN information rest is values in the line is not required

Comment: Just add the characters up to 19th from the previous line to each line that is shorter than 19? `perl -ple '$_.=substr$p,$l,19-$l if ($l=length())<19;$p=$_' input > output`

Comment: Just a curiosity, why Perl? For fixed length records I prefer GNU Awk: `awk -vFIELDWIDTHS='11 8' -vOFS='' '!$2{$2=p}{p=$2}1' input > output`

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the "interesting" part of the previous line and add it when the line begins with "AA ", "BB " or "MTD" (in the last case, only the short portion of the string is replaced):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @repeat;
while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (my ($first, $second) = $line =~ /^MTD.{8}(...)(.*?) /) {
        $repeat[0] //= $first;
        $repeat[1] = $second;
        substr $line, 11, 3, $repeat[0];
    }
    if ($line =~ /^([AB])\1 /) {
        substr $line, 11, 0, $repeat[0] . $repeat[1];
    }
    print "$line\n";
}
```

Comment: In my file for MTD line there is subsequent line AA and BB lines only for these I need add ARN value.rest of them will remain as is, and it is not fixed length of 19....

Comment: @user36697: Then please give a more detailed specification.

Comment: Hi Choroba, Can you pls. look into the above example 2 and let me know...

Comment: @user36697: Now, my script gives the expected outputs in both the cases. I am not sure it is general enough, though, as the specification is still unclear.

Comment: my sepec is general MTD lines can be many in the file....